# firefox on alpine linux does not display characters

Tags: firefox, alpine-linux

**tl;dr** firefox on alpine does not display any characters, only missing character code glyphs

I installed firefox `apk add firefox`. Running firefox (over remote X tunnelled via ssh) no characters are rendered. There are only missing character code value glyphs

[image: firefox on alpine missing character glpyhs]

I suspect another package of character images needs to be installed.

alpine linux version `3.12.1`.
Package `firefox` is version `firefox-84.0.2-r0`.

Comment: You forgot to add fonts package. Can you post the output of ```apk info -v | grep ttf```?
You can add a couple of fonts like dejavu and liberation with: ```apk add ttf-dejavu ttf-liberation```.

Comment: I ran `apk add ttf-dejavu ttf-liberation ttf-freefont ttf-opensans ttf-font-awesome`. Firefox now shows actual characters. Thanks @FrancescoColista !
If you'd like to officially Answer The Question, please go ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing font packages.

You can add a couple of fonts like dejavu and liberation with: `apk add ttf-dejavu ttf-liberation`